# file is uploaded into folder but path is not stored into database

Tags: php, mysql

i was trying to insert image into server folder and then path into database but i can able to upload file into server folder unable to store any thing into database like File Type,file size and file name (i mean path). i am new to php please try to help me out.

using php and mysql

**index.php**

```
<form action="upload.php" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
 <input type="file" name="file" />
 <button type="submit" name="btn-upload">upload</button>
</form>
```

**upload.php**

```
if(isset($_POST['btn-upload']))
{    

 $file = rand(1000,100000)."-".$_FILES['file']['name'];
 $file_loc = $_FILES['file']['tmp_name'];
 $file_size = $_FILES['file']['size'];
 $file_type = $_FILES['file']['type'];
 $folder="uploads/";

 // new file size in KB
 $new_size = $file_size/1024;  
 // new file size in KB

 // make file name in lower case
 $new_file_name = strtolower($file);
 // make file name in lower case

 $final_file=str_replace(' ','-',$new_file_name);

 if(move_uploaded_file($file_loc,$folder.$final_file))
 {
  $sql="INSERT INTO tbl_uploads(file,type,size) VALUES('$final_file','$file_type','$new_size')";
  $smt=$db->prepare($sql);
 $smt->execute();
```

**view.php**

```
<table width="80%" border="1">
    <tr>
    <th colspan="4">your uploads...<label><a href="index.php">upload new files...</a></label></th>
    </tr>
    <tr>
    <td>File Name</td>
    <td>File Type</td>
    <td>File Size(KB)</td>
    <td>View</td>
    </tr>
    <?php
 $sql="SELECT * FROM tbl_uploads";
 $result=$db->query($sql);
    while($row=$result->fetch_object())
 {
  ?>
        <tr>
        <td><?php echo $row['file'] ?></td>
        <td><?php echo $row['type'] ?></td>
        <td><?php echo $row['size'] ?></td>
        <td><a href="uploads/<?php echo $row['file'] ?>" target="_blank">view file</a></td>
        </tr>
        <?php
 }
 ?>
    </table>
```

**table details**
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ci7SQ.png)

```
 CREATE TABLE `tbl_uploads` (
      `id` int(10) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
      `file` varchar(100) NOT NULL,
      `type` varchar(10) NOT NULL,
      `size` int(11) NOT NULL,
      PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
    ) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;
```

Comment: Try to Echo Your Query. and tell which error you get.

Comment: Are you getting any error?

Comment: file is inserted successfully no error but any of info not stored in database

Comment: @TarangP i had done it but no error.

Comment: Is your query correct? Try inserting into the database using this query directly into the MySQL database. Check if that is working. Also, echo all 3 variables to see if they have the correct value you need.

Comment: @GopalNaikGuguloth Try to echo $sql and than enter exit; And show me what your query is .

Comment: @TarangP  INSERT INTO tbl_uploads (file,type,size) VALUES ('91498-1.pdf','application/pdf','1487.2470703125')

Comment: Please Post Your Scema

Comment: @TarangP  i had uploaded db details please go through it

Comment: @GopalNaikGuguloth First of all your query is not correct for a prepared statement. Also how do you make your database connection? have you verified that you are successfully connecting to the db?

Comment: @GopalNaikGuguloth please check my revised answer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

i execute the code.
The Problem is in your Schema

```
Data truncation: Data too long for column 'type' at row 1
```

Try to Run Following Than Perform Insertions It Would be insert

```
ALTER TABLE `users` CHANGE `size` `size` INT(30) NOT NULL;
```

Comment: even though i cant store values in database

Comment: size` int(11) NOT NULL, and you pass more than 10 So sql statment produce error . its better if you change it int to varchar(300).and than it would works fine.and also reffer this https://www.w3schools.com/PhP/php_mysql_prepared_statements.asp

Answer (score 1):

Given you have successfully connected to your database, you will have to modify your sql statement as follows:

```
$stmt = $db->prepare("INSERT INTO tbl_uploads(`file`,`type`,`size`) VALUES(?,?,?))"; 

$stmt->bindParam(1, $final_file);
$stmt->bindParam(2, $file_type);
$stmt->bindParam(3, $new_size);

if($stmt->execute())
{
     echo 'Success';
}
else
{
     echo 'Failed!';
}
```

Also make sure you have proper field types with enough lengths to store your data in the table.

In case if you haven't made and verified your db connection, you can do so by adding below code to the top of your script or just before adding the record:

```
<?php
$dsn = 'mysql:host=localhost;dbname=YOURDBNAME';

try{
  $dbh = new PDO($dsn, 'db_username', 'db_password');
}catch (PDOException $e){
  die($e->getMessage());
}
```

be sure to replace YOURDBNAME, db_username, db_password with appropriate values.

you should also check out these references: 
http://php.net/manual/en/pdo.prepared-statements.php